# To prove convergence in L1 given that convergence in integral and absolutly convergence in integral

Tags: real-analysis, measurable-functions

I am solving an exercise of real analysis:

Given that $f_n $ and $f$ is lebesgue integrable on $E$,$f_n\to f$ a.e. when $n\to\infty$.

If $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Ef_n(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_Ef(x)\mathrm{d}x,
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_E|f_n(x)|\mathrm{d}x=\int_E|f(x)|\mathrm{d}x$$
then prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_E|f_n(x)-f(x)|\mathrm{d}x=0.$$
My approach is as follows：

Since$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq|f_n(x)|+|f(x)|$, and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_E|f_n(x)|+|f(x)|\mathrm{d}x=2\int_E|f(x)|\mathrm{d}x,$$
by the generalized dominated convergence theorem,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_E|f_n(x)-f(x)|\mathrm{d}x=\int_E\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\mathrm{d}x=\int_E|\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)-f(x)|\mathrm{d}x=0.$$
I thought the answer is just like this, until I found the answer of this question is so long that I think my solution may has some wrong.

So, where am I wrong? Is this exercise not really obvious?

update:

---

Knowing that Scheffé's lemma is much stronger than this exercise, I confirm that my proof is correct and this stupid exercise is not really good for understand the property of $L^1$ convergence.

Comment: For DCT you would need some $g(x)\geq |f_n(x)-f(x)|,\forall n$ s.t. $g \in L^1$. Have you found it?

Comment: @Snoop I didn't use that version of DCT, but the GENERALIZED version that doesn't need to make $g(x)$ independent of n.